Is it possible to produce cheap saccharide oil solely from fossil fuels? I’m meaning cheaper than currently based agriculture carbohydrates prices
Simple question : in my country with the rise of conservatism is rising the calls to have food containing as most as sugar possible with lowest nutrients/vitamins as possible in order to decrease costs as low as possible (sounds like a worldbuilding scenario but this isn’t fiction though understandable with half of the local population having less than 27€ per months to eat).
So I thought about this case : when peoples become poorer and poorer, food charities go bankrupts thus leaving peoples starving, then politically, this means only short term health matters and medium/long term health is crossed off as promoting healthy diet or food safety standards is almost communism…
As a result would it be possible to completely cut the link between agriculture and food and having mankind using fossil fuels derivatives for it’s food ?
The underlying idea is although measured differently (Watts or joul vs large calories) a given quantity of energy that use fossil fuels is still far cheaper than the same quantity in food for humans.
If yes, would it enable having 2700 calories of saccharide or edible oil per day for less than 35¢ ?
Important note for answering
Please don’t confuse weight or Volume prices and energy prices.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"If yes, would it enable having 2700 calories of saccharide per day for less than 35¢ ?" FYI: The bulk price of wheat is only 14¢ for 2700 kcal

@Nosajimiki No, 705grams of wheat don t cost 14¢. Even at wholesale prices without transportation. Please check more current price sources.

@user2284570 I did, and they are the correct global averages, but prices vary by region.  Stuff in Europe costs more than the global average, but your question does not specify any specific region.

@user2284570 one of the problems this question has suffered is your insistence that food today is more expensive than the cost of processing petroleum. What you haven't figured out from all the various comments is that doesn't matter. Do you actually care if anyone here believes you or not? "In your world" food is so expensive that it makes sense to ask this question. If you stop arguing with everyone and [edit] your question to reflect the "reality" of food on your world, all of these problems would disappear.

@JBH because that kind of thing is eco'omically viable with heavy oils https://www.topsoe.com/blog/worlds-only-natural-gas-to-gasoline-plant-in-operation-in-turkmenistan

@user2284570 I don't know what the conversion of natural gas to gasoline has to do with this... it's irrelevant. Your question was never the problem. Your premise was the problem. Too many people couldn't see past your premise, which is also irrelevant.

It's undoubtedly possible to synthesise carbohydrates from the hydrocarbons in fossil fuels. Industrial chemistry can make an extraordinary range of compounds starting from petroleum. Starting from coal would probably involve more synthesis steps.
This would be far more expensive than just growing, harvesting and processing plants. The synthesis processes would require a lot of expensive industrial facilities, and would consume a lot of energy. They'd also have to be run to rather high standards to avoid poisoning people who ate the synthetic carbohydrates with side products and contaminants. Plants come with lots of built-in chemistry to avoid that problem.
This isn't a route to cheap food.

As John Clark put it in his classic work Ignition!, "a good chemist, given a little time and money, can derive just about anything organic, up to RNA, from petroleum if he wants to." The problem is that what constitutes "a little time and money" in the propellant industry is very different from the food industry.

But it is a route to the OP's dystopic imaginary world where, for whatever reason that the OP isn't obligated to explain, food is replaced with crude oil. You've pitched the wrong frame challenge - it doesn't matter if it's cheaper to grow/harvest food. It's the OP's problem to rationalize why growing/harvesting food doesn't make sense. Frankly, @Cadence's comment is pretty useful to the OP.

@JBH: As I read the question, the OP is asking if it's possible to replace agriculture with fossil fuel as a way of making food cheaper.

@JohnDallman That's neither what was asked in the title nor what was asked in the post body. Title: "Is it possible to produce cheap saccharide solely from fossil fuels?" Post: "would it enable having 2700 calories of saccharide per day for less than 35¢ ?" I see your point concerning the bold paragraph, but the OP hasn't explained why food is expensive in his/her world. But that's the backstory and the OP is only lacking experience with separating the backstory from the problem.

@JohnDallman building factories would be 1 time costs/investment… I only care about the long run : extracting oil from sand in Canada costs almost more energy than it returns, yet it’s profitable. Compare also the KW/h costs : there’s plenty of room for fossil fuels to costs more and remain more competitive compared to agriculture.

@JohnDallman They'd also have to be run to rather high standards to avoid poisoning people who ate the synthetic carbohydrates with side products and contaminants ignore the standards, cancer isn’t a painful disease despite peoples dieing from it in horrible way in reality. Myself I was once tasked in performing flavour synthesis in cyclohexane and did very little to ensure there were no cyclohexane left in the final product. I’m not saying it shouldn’t be toxic but just not toxic enough to make outright sick or kill.

@JBH : it’s rather about peoples becoming too poor to afford enough carbohydrates from agriculture at current prices rather than food prices actually increasing which in turns props political leaders who promote less food safety standards along less healthy diets that are also more environmentally damaging in the name to cut down costs.

@user2284570 Read my post in the comment tree to your question - how you ask a question here matters a lot and bringing up details that don't actually matter to the question will get your question closed. John's frame challenge only makes sense if the economic reality of food vs. oil exists as it does in today's world, because he's right - it'll never be cheaper to convert oil than to grow food unless you've created a story rationale to justify expensive food. If that doesn't matter to the question (can I convert oil...), leave it at the door or risk muddying the water.

Voted to close: this much argument indicates the question is unclear.

He does not say that the cost of food goes up, just that people are too poor to afford it.

Pharmaceuticals would be the existing example. But they have much different price structure vs cheap food.

Methane.  Formaldehyde.  Formose reaction.
Start with methane* from natural gas.
Burn it, badly, to produce formaldehyde.  Gas ovens sometimes do this by accident, but apparently it is not easy to do completely - industrial formaldehyde production goes another route because it is hard to make the right amount of oxygen go to each methane.  To do it this way so that you can (partly) burn your hydrocarbon and eat it too, you'll have to invent a catalyst.  I think someone might do that IRL (the first part I mean) and make a lot of money.
Carbohydrates are CH2O(n).  Formaldehyde is CH2O.  Use the formose reaction to make carbohydrates and amino acids.  There's some history to this - ribose from formaldehyde on hydroxylapatite rock might have been the very first chemical reaction on the path to the origin of all life.
If the agriculture prohibition can be bent a little, microorganisms could be used to do a variety of biochemistry on these products in order to give the appearance of a safe and palatable food.
Some people may find this method of food production a bit implausible, but here in the U.S. we just had a festival called "Halloween", where millions of little kids beg for treats made by a couple of big corporations using an ingredient called PGPR, meaning "polyglycerol polyricinoleate".  The "ricin" come from the same root as the famous umbrella-tip poison, namely the scientific name for the castor oil plant.  (Fear not, we avoid security issues with the castor beans by importing them from the Middle East, where farmers diligently cook the toxin on-site to avoid it being used for mass poisonings)  Using PGPR allows companies to use less of the expensive cocoa butter, which can be sold in cosmetics instead.  Now if you can make kids line up and beg for treats made out of castor oil, I think you can plausibly make food rations out of natural gas.
* Methane is by far the most common component of natural gas, but the next most common is ethane.  Add one oxygen to ethane, anywhere, and you have ethanol, which your populace will eagerly consume even though it does taste awful.
Note: I see there's an edited criterion in the question about prices.  These aren't really relevant, but let's go.  Natural gas somewhere is 2.79 USD/MMBtu today.  That's a commodity price, not a retail price, but your factory will be big.  1 MMBtu = 1000000 Btu.  Methane is 23811 Btu/lb.  1 kg = 2.203 lb.  So natural gas is 2.79 USD/MMBtu x 1 MMBtu / 1000000 Btu x 23811 Btu / lb x 2.203 lb / kg = 0.146 USD / kg.  The combustion is CH4 + O2 -> CH2O + H2O, so we get 30 g CH2O / 1 mol CH2O x 1 mol CH2O / 1 mol CH4 x 1 mol CH4 / 16 g CH4 = 1.875 kg of formaldehyde for every kg of natural gas.  Assuming a perfect catalyst for a reaction we haven't invented one for yet, that is.  The formaldehyde is converted perfectly (in theory) to carbohydrate, which is reckoned on food labels as 4 kcal/g.  So we have 0.146 USD / kg CH4 x 1 kg CH4 / 1.875 kg sugars x 1 kg sugars / 1000 g sugars x 1 g / 4 kcal = 1.95E-5 USD / kcal... x 2700 kcal = 0.0526 USD (5.26 cents) per 2700 "Calories".  This price does not count the offset income generated by partially burning the natural gas during processing.  I can't comment on how plausible it would be that real-world inefficiencies would bring this price above 35 cents.

In my question the peoples asks for harmfull food as the consequence of paying less (as long as it don t kill ouright). The comment was moved to chat but quoting my own grandfather stop wasting your money on food and worrying on cancer and diabetes. You know the doctors, they know on how to cure everything (sounds like worldbuilding fiction but it s not). Of course, that didn t work out for him.

@user2284570 - An approach very similar to yours was used historically for production of sugar from wood.  Oil of vitriol (sulfuric acid, flavored with various metals) could catalyze this reaction.  The use of lead vitriol led to mass deaths.  Unfortunately, even with AI tools the modern internet can't find me a reference to this case, which I know I read about on the internet before.

For prices, just look at the actual commodity cost of formaldehyde which is $0.35-0.45/kg throughout most of the world, or $0.15/kg in China.  However, you have a downstream problem.  Sugars made from chemically reacted formaldehyde, formose, is highly toxic in large quantities; so, you'd need to go through the costly process of feeding the formaldehyde to microbes that will slowly turn it into digestible sugars like glucose or fructose because in biochemistry, it's not enough to achieve the right chemical formula, you need the right molecular shape to.

While formaldehyde is a good start, by the time you are done with your whole process, you will have a product that is probably several dollars per kg.

@Nosajimiki do you man formaldehyde is a sugar ?

@user2284570 No, formaldehyde is not a sugar.  Sugars are C6H12O6(n), not CH2O(n).  The ratios of elements are the same, but sugar by definition contains a hexagon of carbon atoms with 6 Oxygen and 12 Hydrogen atoms coming off of it in one of many possible patterns.  What I'm saying is that the proposed solution of generating Formose from Formaldehyde won't work because Formose is a toxic shape of sugar whereas edible sugars like Glucose and Fructose can at this point in time only be created by biological processes.

@Nosajimiki - any solution will have research required, because nobody IRL makes food out of fossil fuel.  Come up with the right catalyst, and the product shouldn't be that much more expensive than the raw materials.  I think formaldehyde is expensive because it is currently made from methanol, which is being made from carbon dioxide, in a roundabout way.  I would expect the formose reaction could be made chiral and produce a relatively small mix of products.  Those might be separable with this

@MikeSerfas I agree that RnD is required, that is why I looked up a wide range of simple, commercially useful chemicals derived from crude oil when I wrote my own answer to get an idea of what comparable products cost, and found that they pretty much all had commodity costs of about $900-1500 per ton. So, expecting an as of now undiscovered process to be much cheaper than comparable processes that do exist is not very realistic.

If it has not been discovered yet, it means you will likely need to do a complex series of chemical reactions that each add cost to get to the end result. So, I would actually expect it to be closer to the high end of this range.

I think of sci-fi novels as willing to allow major breakthroughs so long as they are physically possible.  Breakthroughs do happen, after all.  In the end you handwave up some explanation that you know is very unlikely to work.  "The soliton-laser* gives the methane particles a precise vibrational energy, which interacts with this terahertz frequency in the presence of argon to catalyze the transfer of a single oxygen atom without further reaction"  Note: I looked it up and there actually is such a thing as a pure-quartic soliton laser, FWIW. :)

As of today 3 November 2024, petroleum costs about 70 US dollars per barrel, or about 0.41 US dollars per kilogram; sugar (in bulk) costs about 0.46 US dollars per kilogram.
One kilogram of petroleum provides about 44 MJ of energy, or about 10,500 kcal, about 4 times as much as the 2,700 kcal target given by the question. This means that from the point of view of pure energy, 250 grams of petroleum can provide the required 2,700 kcal for about 0.10 US dollars.
On the other hand, the question wants the 2,700 kcal in the form of sugar. The energy density of sugar is about 17 MJ per kilogram, or about 4,000 kcal per kilogram. Sugar costs about 0.46 US dollars per kilogram when bought in bulk; this means that from the point of view of pure energy, 600 grams of sugar can provide the required 2,700 kcal for about 0.28 US dollars.
Overall, to get 2,700 kcal one can buy 600 grams sugar of agricultural origin for 0.28 US dollars, or one can buy 250 grams of petroleum for about 0.10 US dollars and try to find a process which can convert 1 kg of petroleum into 2.5 kg of sugar for less than 0.80 US dollars.

You can't just look at potential energy.  The point is to use the petroleum for its raw materials to synthesize sugar which means that you need 1kg in, 1kg out regardless of how much potential energy is lost in the process.

@Nosajimiki: The way the chemistry works is that from 1 kg of petroleum you ideally get about 2.5 kg of sugar. (Because petroleum is a mixture of hydrocarbons, more or less $\ce{CH2}$, and sugar is a carbohydrate $\ce{CH2O}$.) Your 1 kg in giving 1 kg out is missing the oxygen which is available for free in the atmosphere. Maybe I should have explained it?

Sorry, I forgot about the O2 having to come from another source.  However, crude is not exactly, the same ratio of C:H as sugar. The presence of octane means its more like 1 carbon atom per 1.82 hydrogen atoms; so,even if the oxygen is coming from the air, it's more like a 1.95 kg of sugar per kg of crude... plus crude averages 2% other elements; so, 1.91:1

Bio reactors:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioreactor
They take in a raw ingredient,
We already have dna-altered bacteria and yeast that can prodcues about anything. So the agriculture argument does not hold- one needs a bacteria that devours oil, alter it to produce saccharose and then have it life in optimized conditions within a reactor. Its done on mass today. The problem is, follow up organisms who devour the saccharose, so you need sterility to start with- and a sort of one way gate, to drop out the produce and refill sterilized oil.
Also not everything in oil is eatable, you would have some "slag" removal ocassionally.
You might also need warmth for heating and filtered gas needed by the microorganisms.
Organsims of choice:
Marinobacter, Oceanospiralles, Pseudomonas, and Alkanivorax
Find your own main character here, who is easiest to alter and maintain.
You either trade time, quality or money for this.
Micro-organisms are time-intensive, aka slow, that is why we mainly use them for expensive things like medicine and rarely food.
You could speed it up- by having- a futuristic all organic refinery organism, that basically grows directly into the oil field, tapping geothermal for energy and growing the food. You would have a organic looking hole in the ground that shits food into the world. That would make it cheap and it might scale with enough thermal vents.
You can build chemical refineries, which basically just push the sludge through. But they are similar to conventional refineries, in that they need the energy budget for a whole city, expensive parts and additional chemicals produced externally.
Finally, you could do it in a sterile environment, like some moons in this solar system. There, a food refinery, could produce from raw methane and methanol the sugars, freeze them and gun them into longterm trajectory. The MANA (Manufactured Automated Nutrition Allocation) would rain from the sky after drifting in space for a long time.

And you should consider developping chemistry to fight germs that might kill your bacterias. Sounds like agriculture to me.

Agriculture that requires plenty of oil, which itself requires high-tech to drill for, high-tech needs specialized labour, specialized labour needs agriculture. It bootstraps itself!

If the goal is making petroleum into something edible, don't make it into sugar - make it into margarine!
The Fischer-Tropsch process was invented in the 1920s to turn coal into liquid hydrocarbons. Mostly this was (and still is!) used to make fuel oil and lubricant, but during the Second World War Germany (which had a lot of coal) used this process to produce "coal butter" which U-Boat crews would get as part of their rations.
Since you're starting with oil instead of coal, the process would be a little different - you don't need to produce liquid hydrocarbons, but rather remove the toxic impurities from the hydrocarbons you already have. But the end result has already been shown to be possible!
It's hard to say what techniques would make this practical today, though. One of the benefits of coal butter was apparently that it wouldn't go rancid over the weeks and months sitting in a U-Boat's larder. Food preservation technology has improved since then, so in the modern day there's cheaper and more nutritious ways to accomplish that goal.
And it took an unusual situation to make it remotely cost effective: a country with abundant sources of fossil fuels but which couldn't effectively farm because they were engaged in a total war. Admittedly that is not as unusual a situation as I wish it were.

Not sure of the price compared to agriculture products from america at that time. A side effect is only sacharrides makes you feel not hungry. You can feed on ketones but hungryness depends on sugar level in blood.

Really? I've heard the opposite - that sugars give you calories but don't make you feel full. Certainly a diet based mainly around fat can work - consider traditional Inuit hunters, or more recently the Atkins weight-loss diet. Your dystopian country will probably want to make sure people get vitamin supplements and an occasional vegetable, as no single food can supply all a person's nutritional needs. But malnutrition aside, people can definitely get their calories from fat!

Price is definitely an issue tho. I'm sure if WW2 Germany could have bought American or Russian grain, or grown enough of their own, they would have done that instead.

Was given 1 liter of edible oil. I thought I could avoid rice or flour but 200ml and 3 hours later I was too hungry to not have to buy rice and flour. As I wrote in my question, peoples would ignore malnutrition. Personally I do rely on chip nutrient pills as I normally can’t buy vegetables nor meat (and food charities that aren’t bankrupt are open only from time to time on a first‑in best dressed basis).

You can only use  petroleum to replace the expensive parts of food, not the cheap parts
Cereal grains like flour and corn are only about \$175 per ton*.  Petroleum is about \$550 per ton and non-byproduct things made from petroleum start at about \$1000 per ton meaning that if you are only trying to achieve sustenance level living, without regard for nutrition it is much cheaper and healthier to live off of cereal grains than synthetic or organic sugar.  Your goal should not be to make a synthetic source of calories from petroleum, but instead to replace expensive flavoring with cheaper flavorings.
This way you can bring the actual cost of the meals way down.  More importantly for your starving masses, this will force your farmers who are currently growing these cash crops free to pivot to staple crops like wheat and corn which give much larger calorie yields per acre.  This means the actual material cost of your people need to live off of only \$0.13-0.17 per day; though the actual price will likely be closer to \$0.75-1.50 per day when you include all the costs and markups of packaging, distribution, and retail.
That said, your well to do population will not tolerate just eating wheat and corn all the time; so, you need to "trick" them into abandoning real food in favor of synthetic flavorings if you want to pivot to a staple centered agricultural economy.  Salt and sugar are are good options because they are cheap flavorings at just \$220 and \$560 per ton respectively for giving your lower-middle class something tasty but not too expensive in terms of cost or land use. These can not really be improved on by synthetic flavoring though because they are still less than \$1000/ton
The biggest overhead in quality food comes from meat, herbs and spices; so, these are what you need to wean your middle class off of if you want to improve your available food supply for the poor. The wholesale cost of common meats and natural food flavorings are as follows:

Chicken, Tuna, Catfish: \$1000-5000/ton
Beef \$5000-10000/ton
Lamb, Cayenne, Fenugreek, Mint Extract: \$10,000-25,000/ton
Basil, Chili Pepper, Cinnamon, Coriander, Cumin, Curry Powder, Garlic Powder, Onion Powder, Oregano, Paprika, Thyme: \$25,000-50,000/ton
Allspice, Cloves, Ginger, Licorice, Lemon Pepper: \$50,000-100,000/ton
Cardamom, Nutmeg, Saffron, Tarragon: \$100,000-1,000,000/ton
Vanilla Bean Extract: Over \$1,000,000/ton

So, if you can synthesize artificial meat and seasoning flavorings to make cereal based foods taste like other stuff, you can significantly reduce the cost of food without sacrificing it's apparent quality.  (It's real quality may be much lower though).  This way your middle class will stop buying seemingly identical but more expensive products made with real food, and it's all supply and demand trickle down from there.
That said, this is not fiction at all. This is exactly what the American food industry has been doing for the past several decades.  For example, nearly all of the Mint and Vanilla extract consumed in the United States is actually made from coal tar or petroleum.  These chemicals only costs about \$1,000-2,000/ton to produce making them WAY cheaper than their natural counterparts, but if we assume sugar and starches could be made from similarly expensive processes, you would not save any money by doing so.
* All prices listed in this answer are bulk, wholesale (commodity) prices.  Actual consumer prices are typically much higher. Also, prices are based on approximate global averages, prices in specific areas may differ.

@user2284570 That is the bulk wholesale cost of production.  Not the consumer cost.  I said specifically in the 3rd paragraph that distribution and preparation is more expensive than the materials themselves. and also tried to clarify that in the foot note that none of this is final consumer pricing.

No cereal grains aren t at 175$ per tons even in Russia without transportation currently (I m indeed meaning wholesale). Rice can be bought at that price but only from countries without sea access which makes transportation costly. Also the right metric is energy costs and not weight of matter.

I m living on poverty with the unhealthy diet recommenced in the said alt media. Flour soup like the ancient romans until the end of the republic. No flavouring ane almost no vitamins.

@user2284570 The Current price of corn is $169/ton https://ycharts.com/indicators/us_corn_price_imfpcp and the current price of flour is $188/ton https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/PWHEAMTUSDM.  Commodity prices change enough that I was averaging for a ballpark figure. Both grains have hit 175 global market values within the past few months though.

@user2284570 the purpose of my answer is not to give the poorest citizens flavor, it's to get the richer citizens to accept artificial flavors so you can replace large wasteful herb and spice farms with more corn and wheat farms so that there are more calories to go around.

Then the price differences between wheat prices in Europe (where I live) and United States illustrate the purpose of my question. The richs have to accept the consequences of who win elections.

Also, if unmilled wheat is an option where you are, you should switch to couscous instead of flour soup.  Unmilled wheat contains most of most of the vitamins, minerals, and essential amino acids that you need, and it stores just as well as milled flour.  Milling requires the removal of most of the good stuff to keep the flour from spoiling.

Yes, the prices in Europe are well above global averages.  The war in Ukraine cut off Europe not just from grain trade, but from key components in industrial fertilizer which has also made producing food in Europe more expensive.  The problem is that the cost of petroleum and natural gas has also proportionally gone up because a lot of that has been cut off/reduced from the war as well; so, the proportions shown in my answer should still hold true, even if exact dollar values are off a bit.

I don t think it s only that. I tried to look buying from Russia in wholesale and without transportation and wheat prices are similar. I rather difference in quality/norms is the real culprit.

@user2284570 When I say "bulk" wholesale... I mean what corporations pay when they buy it by the truckload directly from the source.  When you buy something like a 24kg bag "wholesale" you are paying the rate after it's been marked up by the packaging company, but before the markup of a grocer.  Like here is the US a wholesale hopper truck of flour is about $0.19/kg, but a low end 24kg wholesale bag is about $0.75/kg, and a low end retail bag is about $1.00/kg

The reason I'm using this rate is because using chemistry to turn petroleum into food would require an industrial chemical plant; so, I'm comparing the relative costs that a food processing plant would incur, not an end consumer.

I perfectly understand what wolsale means as I used to buy most of my food upfront every 2 year when I had money. You seems to have no experience in buying almost 2 tons of rice or lentils from source and arrenge for transportation later (especially interesting with 14% of inflation per year). And yes even with avoiding inflation it was up to 40% cheaper than discount stores (in the end I ate eveything). Thr only catch is it was mostly organic food.

@user2284570 Just trying to account for possible misunderstandings.  If you want me to look specifically at current Russian Export rates, the Rusgrain Union is currently suggesting $240 per tonne, which is above the global average.  But that is still much less than the $447.60 per ton set by Western sanction price caps on crude oil or the $522.20 per ton they are averaging on crude oil when you look at their exports across all markets.  So, my point remains: synthetic sugar would be more expensive than cereal grains.

Also, "...the right metric is energy costs and not weight of matter..." is wrong. You can not look at the energy density of crude oil, because you are not using it as a fuel, you are using it as a source of carbon and hydrogen to construct saccharides. There will be a net loss of potential energy when you transform it into digestible compounds; so,1kg of oil becomes 1kg or less of sugar.  Getting more than 1kg of sugar would violate the conservation of mass.

The local political discourse is the United States have lower chemistry standards and higher cancer rates but lower prices and thus safety should be aboslished. Even when looking at energy densities of gasoline, the ratio is still interesting despite gasoline sometimes coming partly through natural gas because of heavy oil.

Another complication with bulk pricing is that it's bulk pricing. You probably cannot get 1 ton of wheat for $175. You certainly can't get 10 kilos of wheat for 1.75. That's a price for multi-thousand-ton purchases between suppliers that can handle that size of shipment (but would be ill-suited to handling thousands or millions of smaller ones).

@Cadence You also can not buy 10 kilos of crude oil and turn it into sugar using what's in your kitchen. So, the only fair comparison is the industrial cost of synthetic sugar to industrially grown food.  Because at the end of the day, even if a bag of flour costs the consumer $1/kg and a factory can mass produce fake sugar for $0.50/kg, the end consumer will not be paying $0.50/kg because it still needs to be marked up for packaging, distribution, and retail; so, it will still cost the consumer more than the flour which has a lower commodity cost.

@Nosajimiki All certainly true. I was just offering that point up to the OP, who seems fixated on the retail price of goods as the determinant of whether it would be economical to convert them.
